# LTL about Fp=TUp, is T really necessary in rewriting F?

Tags: logic, model-checking

I just come up with this question. As written in the book of Logic in Computer Science, one of the important equivalence of LTL is this:
Fp=TUp. And the T means no constraints.

Yet what if I replace the T with (not p)? Does Fp=(not p)Up hold? Since in this case I actually put some constraints (not p) in the formula, but in the meantime there could be no state can satisfy (not p) and p together. And I tried with different LTL formula as p, and as long as p is satisfiable, then for every path with p, it must satisfy Fp and (not p)Up as well.
Does it means that I can rewrite F in this way or there is some counter example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The short answer:**

Yes, both formulas are equivalent and you can rewrite `Fp` also with `(¬p)Up`.

**and a proof:**

We can investigate the problem by looking at the definition of `pUq` (I think it's defined this way in the book Model Checking by Clarke, Grumberg, Peled).

A path s is a model for the formula (written `s ⊨ pUq`):

```
s ⊨ pUq <=>   ∃k: s^k ⊨ q
            ∧ ∀i: 0<=i<k => s^i ⊨ q
```

(With `s^i` being the path `s` with the first `i` steps removed.)

We have (1):

```
s ⊨ (¬p)Up <=>   ∃k: s^k ⊨ p
               ∧ ∀i: 0<=i<k => s^i ⊨ ¬p
```

and (2):

```
s ⊨ TUp <=>   ∃k: s^k ⊨ p
            ∧ ∀i: 0<=i<k => s^i ⊨ true
        <=>   ∃k: s^k ⊨ p
```

We want to show (1) <=> (2) (I renamed the ks to `k1` and `k2` to avoid confusion):

```
    ∃k1: s^k1 ⊨ p
  ∧ ∀i: 0<=i<k1 => s^i ⊨ ¬p
<=>
    ∃k2: s^k2 ⊨ p
```

The direction (1) => (2) is trivial.

For (2) => (1) we have to show that from

```
 ∃k2: s^k2 ⊨ p
```

follows

```
 ∃k1: s^k1 ⊨ p ∧ ∀i: 0<=i<k1 => s^i ⊨ ¬p
```

We know that there exists a value for `k1` (namely `k2`) such that `s^k1 ⊨ p` holds. But what about the second part? We can now just use for `k1` the smallest value such that `s^i ⊨ p` holds. Then the second part is true, because if there would be an `i` such that `s^i ⊨ not p` does not hold, we know that `s^i |= p` holds. But in that case we would have choosen `i` for `k1` because `i` is strictly smaller then `k1`.

So both formulas (1) and (2) are equivalent.